# MacBook Pro OS X and Windows Crash

Tags: bootcamp, macos, crash, windows, kernel-panic

I have a Mac-Book Pro on which i have windows 7 installed on Bootcamp partition, yesterday while working it suddenly crashed, I saw a blue screen for less than half a second and the system restarted and went on to boot windows again and it crashed again.

So i tried booting it to OS X, it booted but i couldn't see anything except for a black screen with a cursor. I searched for solutions to the black screen problem and tried some but none on them worked. So i shut it down to look for the problem in morning.

Now in morning it started misbehaving more, sometimes it would not show `startup Manager` even when `Option` key was pressed and would randomly boot into Windows or OS X. I tried booting in windows in safe mode but it would still crash

[image: crash]

And OS X also started crashing

[image: OS X Crash]

I tried running First Aid in Disk Utility in Recovery Mode (which opened sometimes only, sometimes Mac would ignore CMD+R and go on to boot os of its choice). When i ran First Aid it said

[image]

I also ran Windows repair and it said

[image]

Now i can't understand what the Problem is with my System ?

**ALSO**
A month earlier my hard drive cable had failed and got it replaced.
I had updated OS X El Capitan to OSX Sierra. And i don't think there is a problem with my hard drive becasue i was able to see my windows data while exporting registery data in windows repair .

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with my Hard drive cable, got it replaced.